# Run additional command when rsync detects a file

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I am currently running the following script to make an automatic backup of my Music:

```
#!/bin/bash

while :; do
    rsync -ruv /mnt/hdd1/Music/ /mnt/hdd2/Music/
done
```

Whenever a new file is added to my music folder, it is detected by rsync and it is copied to my other disk. This script runs fine, but I would also like to convert the detected file to an ogg opus file for putting on my phone.

My question is: How do I run a command on a new file found by `rsync -u`?

I will also accept answers which work totally differently, but have the same result.

Comment: Can you use `inotifywait`, instead of `rsync`? It'll detect file changes and print out the relevant paths. Also, `rsync -i` will print out what its doing, so you can do post-processing

Comment: I prefer using tools installed in Ubuntu by default, that's why I used `rsync`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rsync -ruv  /mnt/hdd1/Music /mnt/hdd2/ | sed -n 's|^Music/||p' >~/filelist.tmp
while IFS= read filename
do
    [ -f "$filename" ] || continue
    # do something with file
    echo "Now processing '$filename'"
done <~/filelist.tmp
```

With the `-v` option, `rsync` prints the names of files it copies to stdout.  I use sed to capture just those filenames, excluding the informational messages, to a file.  The filenames in that file can be processed later as you like.

The approach with `sed` above depends on `rsync` displaying filenames starting with the final part of the source directory, e.g. "Music/" in my example above, which is then removed assuming that you don't need it.  Alternately, one could try an explicit approach for excluding noise messages.